# Unable to understand a part of code about Linear Regression from sentdex tutorials on machine learning

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, machine-learning, linear-regression

Was following Sentdex Machine Learning Tutorials in youtube. In the 5th part he does this

```
forecast_out = int(math.ceil(0.01*len(df)))
print(forecast_out)

df['label'] = df[forecast_col].shift(-forecast_out)

X = np.array(df.drop(['label'],1))
X = preprocessing.scale(X)
X = X[:-forecast_out]
X_lately = X[-forecast_out:]


df.dropna(inplace=True)
y = np.array(df['label'])
y = np.array(df['label'])
```

I got completely lost what he was trying to do here. In `int(math.ceil(0.01*len(df)))` he was trying to get the number of days he wants to find the prediction of. After that, he did `df[forecast_col].shift(-forecast_out)` and i couldn't anything after that.

Comment: reading the documentation of [`shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) should help.

Comment: But what was ` (-forecast_out) ` doing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not enough information here, but if this is a time series forecasting problem, then what I think is that `df[forecast_col].shift(-forecast_out)` shifts the forecast column up for 'forecast_out' number of days so that the label column for a specific day would be the number you need to forecast (which is, the number shifted from the future).